How the get last data in Each row in mysqli
Following the picture i want to get the table 2 from table 1. Each Row there have some values and some are null. I want to find the last value in each row with id. In the image it already mention. Please give me a solution.
Thanks
need to summarize table 1 and get the second table with mysqli query
please click the image link

This is what the COALESCE function is for.
SELECT id, COALESCE(var_3,var_2,var_1) FROM data;


Do you know how to "accept" an answer?

sorry i don't know

thanks for your feedback. It was very helpful for me
